# Is there any way to get the single value from HashMap?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

[image]

When I try to retrieve the values from `HashMap` I use `getValue` method. but the `getValue` method is inside the iteration tag in Struts2 so, it is displaying even unwanted values.

How can I avoid this? here in my JSP page i am creating table, where i want to set the `orderdate` from database inside the  `<th>` tags. I mean from `HashMap` i am receiving `orderdate`, result, `dataamount`, count. in `<th>` I want `orderdate` to go and sit and in `<tr>` I want remaining three values to go and sit.  How do I do that?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class JanuaryAction {
    private String from; // creating variables to access input values.
    private String to; // creating variables to access input values.
    Map abc1 = new HashMap(); // Getting the map objects to store tha values

    public Map getAbc1() { /* Creating the setters and getters */
        return abc1;
    }

    public void setAbc1(Map abc1) {
        this.abc1 = abc1;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setAbc(Map<String, String> abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Map<String, List<ReportClass>> map = new HashMap<String, List<ReportClass>>(); // Using
                                                                                    // Map
                                                                                    // interface
                                                                                    // implementing
                                                                                    // hashmap

    public Map<String, List<ReportClass>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, List<ReportClass>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        String fromdate = getFrom();
        System.out.println(fromdate);
        String todate = getTo();
        System.out.println(todate);

        Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultset = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >='"
                        + fromdate + "' AND OrderDate <='" + todate + "' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace");

        while (resultset.next()) {
            String marketplace = resultset.getString(1);// get the first column
                                                        // in marketplace
            String orderdate = resultset.getString(2);// get the second column
                                                        // in orderdate
            Double datamount = resultset.getDouble(3);// get the third column in
                                                        // datamount
            Integer count = resultset.getInt(4);// get the fourth column in
                                                // count
            Double result = resultset.getDouble(5); // get the fifth column in
                                                    // result
            ReportClass a = new ReportClass(); // create an object to access
                                                // pojo class.

            a.setMarketplace(marketplace); // setting the values in pojo class
            a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
            a.setDataamount(datamount);
            a.setCount(count);
            a.setResult(result);

            if (map.get(marketplace) != null) { // if the value in marketplace
                                                // is null then go to else
                                                // statement or go to if
                                                // statement.
                map.get(marketplace).add(a); // using the key add one complete
                                                // row values from a to
                                                // marketplace
            } else {
                List<ReportClass> optionsVO = new ArrayList<ReportClass>(); // create
                                                                            // a
                                                                            // list
                                                                            // optionsVo
                optionsVO.add(a); // store Reportclass values in List.
                map.put(marketplace, optionsVO); // storing it in map.
                /* System.out.println(map.get(marketplace).toString()); */
            }

        }
        Set s = map.entrySet(); // A map entry (key-value pair).creating Set
                                // interface.
        Iterator i = s.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {

            List<ReportClass> tempList = (List<ReportClass>) ((Entry) i.next()).getValue(); // creating
                                                                                            // a
                                                                                            // temporary
                                                                                            // list

            for (ReportClass reportClassObj : tempList) {
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getMarketplace());// display
                                                                    // values.
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getDataamount());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getOrderdate());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getCount());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getResult());
            }
        }

        /* System.out.println(map.size()); */
        return "success";
    }
}
```

in my JSP I have a code:

```
<s:iterator var="studentEntry" status="stat" value="map.entrySet()">  
Key: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getKey()}"/> 
Value: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getValue()}"/><br>  

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Do not make us guess what you are doing and show the code.

Comment: Give us some code, please!

Comment: As to JSP/EL, just specify the key you'd like to get the value for? E.g. `${bean.map.key}` or `${bean.map['key.with.periods']}`. Or does Struts2 it differently?

Comment: check i updated with code

Comment: What do you mean "unwanted values"?

Comment: Is your example related? Marketplace? Student? Am I missing something?. Unrelated but as a suggestion, change `map.get(marketplace) != null` for `map.containsKey(marketplace)`

Comment: sorry for confusing..its nothing to do with student. please ignore student

Comment: i mean from hashmap i am receiving orderdate, result, dataamount, count. in <th> i want orderdate to go and sit and in <tr> i want remaining three values to go and sit.

Comment: So do you want to iterate this `List<ReportClass>` also?

Comment: yes u are absolutely correct

Comment: In the future please only provide the related code, in this case, a hash, the action getter, and the JSP.

Comment: Wow, Aukland is skyrocketing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code, it must work.

```
<s:iterator value="map"> 
<s:iterator value="key">
<s:iterator value="value">
<th><s:property value="orderdate"/></th>
<td rowspan="4"><s:property value="marketplace"/></td>
<tr> <td><s:property value="dataamount"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><s:property value="count"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><s:property value="result"/></td></tr>
</s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you group entries you have to iterate groups first, then other entries by group through get all values or choose the group which you want to iterate.

```
<s:iterator value="map">  
 <s:iterator var="studentEntry" value="value">
  ReportClass: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.toString()}"/><br> 
 </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to use `entrySet` just use `map` variable as `value` attribute of `<s:iterator>` tag and `value` keyword as value of second iterator. Then you can directly reference properties of your `ReportClass` inside the iterator in `<s:property>` tag.

```
<s:iterator value="map">  
  <s:iterator value="value">
    <table>        
      <tr><th colspan="3"><s:property value="orderdate"/></th></tr>
      <tr>
        <td><s:property value="dataamount"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="count"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="result"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Your answer looks very close to me. Is it possible to get the table which i showed in the image

Comment: Your question is about getting values from the map and this is the answer. Accept/upvote it and if you have another question ask a new one.

Comment: As i clearly mentioned my values from the map should sit in the table accordingly as i shown in the image, is it possible mate.? surely i will upvote and accept once i am completely satisfied...